# css th:hover to change background - color

Tags: css

i have table with below structure:

```
     <table class="cedvel">
            <caption>
                count:
                <%:Html.Encode(TempData["RowsCount"])%></caption>
     <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th id="thAfield1" class="field1,asc">
                        <span>field1</span><span id="spanAfield1" class="spanAscDesc">↑↓</span>
                    </th>
                    <th id="thfild2" class="field2,asc">
                        <span>field2</span> <span id="spanfield2" class="spanAscDesc">↑↓</span>
                    </th>
................................
     </thead>
            <tbody>
                <%if (Model.<----->.Count() > 0)
                  {
                      foreach (var abonent in Model.<---->)
                      {%>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        data
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        data
                    </td>
................................
    </tr>
     <tr class="noData">
                    <td colspan="11">
                        no info
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <% }%>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

now i want to change background - color when hovering on th. but can not do it. but simply i can change color when hovering on tr. but on th i can not.

```
table.cedvel th
{
    background-color: #c3dde0;
    background-image: url(../Content/SiteImages/1.png);
    border-width: 1px;
    padding: 8px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #a9c6c9;
}
table.cedvel th:hover
{
    background-color: Red;
}
```

i simply setting background-image: none when hovering. here was my problem. when i hovered on it. it changed background color. but my pic. hided it.

Comment: show some css that is used here

Comment: Works for me. See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3wJZn/1/).

Comment: yes you are right. i saw it. but can not find problem. i will search the problem

Comment: It could be a specificity issue. Try a more specific selector, and see if it works.

Comment: i found solution i removed   background-image: url(../Content/SiteImages/1.png); from table.cedvel th. and not it works. but i don't want to remove image

Comment: friends thanks for help i change my css to : table.cedvel th:hover
{
    color: Red;
    background-color: Red;
    background-image: none;
}
table.cedvel th
{
    background-color: #c3dde0;
    background-image: url(../Content/SiteImages/1.png);
    border-width: 1px;
    padding: 8px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #a9c6c9;
} not it works :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/jomanlk/Bcayc/ It works form e

You probably have an issue with your CSS.

Comment: yes i have test simple table it works. you are right i have issue with my css

Comment: If you post the CSS and the final output of the table - not the code that generates it - on fiddle, we could have a look.

Comment: look to my comment for melhosseiny

Comment: Yup, you can't have a background image and a color unless the image is smaller than the background area.

Answer (score 1):

```
table.cedvel th {
    background-color: #c3dde0;
    background-image: url(../Content/SiteImages/1.png);
}

table.cedvel th:hover {
    background-color: red;
    background-image: none;
}
```